# "CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found" in Unity3d Android build

Tags: android, nginx, unity-game-engine

I have valid cert from RapidSSL GeoTrust Inc. But when I've tried to send request to my server from Android device, got error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

I'm using nginx on server. If I open url in browser, it looks ok. How can I make it work for Android build from Unity3d?

Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        root /var/www/my_server.net;
        server_name my_server.net;

        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|json|sd)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            access_log off;
            expires 1m;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }


        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /var/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/cert.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        error_page 404 /404.json;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Comment: Does `/var/cert.crt` include the intermediate certificates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was cause of my `.crt` doesn't include intermediate cert.

[This](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO17482) instruction could help you to setup nginx correct with RapidSSL certificate.

After you had got you cert, you should make concatenated file of the Intermediate CA and the SSL Certificate with:

```
cat IntermediateCA.crt >> ssl_concatenated _certificate.crt
```

And then use this concatenated file in nginx config:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl_concatenated _certificate.crt;
```

And on [this](https://cryptoreport.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp) page you can check,  if your certificate is installed correctly. You should see something like this:

[image]

Also, it gives you tips to secure your server. For example:

[image]

P.S. Richard Smith, thanks for the tip.